# How to access variable in Document.swift from another class?

Tags: swift, core-data

In CoreData document I have an entity SpaceLocation which is set of different SpaceLocations. One of them is default / current one, necessary for editing document.

It's defined in main Document.swift as:

```
@objc var defaultSpaceLocation: SpaceLocation {

    return SpaceLocation.defaultSpaceLocation(in: managedObjectContext!)
}

@objc var currentSpaceLocation: SpaceLocation {
    get {
        if _currentSpaceLocation == nil {
            willChangeValue(for: \Document.currentSpaceLocation)
            _currentSpaceLocation = defaultSpaceLocation
            didChangeValue(for: \Document.currentSpaceLocation)
        }
        return _currentSpaceLocation!
    }

    set {
        willChangeValue(for: \Document.currentSpaceLocation)
        _currentSpaceLocation = newValue
        didChangeValue(for: \Document.currentSpaceLocation)
    }
}
```

and in SpaceLocation class as:

```
class func defaultSpaceLocation(in moc: NSManagedObjectContext) -> SpaceLocation {
        let spaceLocationsRequest = NSFetchRequest<SpaceLocation>(entityName: "SpaceLocation")
        var result:SpaceLocation? = nil
        do {
            let spaceLocations = try moc.fetch(spaceLocationsRequest)
            result = spaceLocations.filter {$0.isBaseLocation}.first!
        }
        catch {
            Swift.print("•••• ERROR ••••", #file, #function, "Couldn't get Default Location")
        }

        return result!
    }
}
```

I access to currentSpaceLocation by:

```
(NSDocumentController.shared.currentDocument as?Document)?.currentSpaceLocation
```

but it works only if document is in foreground. When app goes background `NSDocumentController.shared.currentDocument` becomes `nil` so I cannot access `document.currentSpaceLocation`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: you mean application in background state?

Comment: Yes. When I click on window from different application.

Comment: no lines of code executes while app is in background state.

Comment: but during switching to background? I can see the results: when in foreground: 
SpaceLocation <SpaceLocation: 0x604000090f90> (entity: SpaceLocation; id: 0x60400022dd60 <x-coredata://5FBA33A8-C37C-4242-A7FE-C3D67511F5D9/SpaceLocation/p37> ; data: {
    axisSpots = "<relationship fault: 0x604000435480 'axisSpots'>";
    isBaseLocation = 1;
    locationValues = "<relationship fault: 0x6040004354a0 'locationValues'>";
    name = "default space location";
})
When in background:
No publisher, no SpaceLoc

Comment: Please read the life cycle of application. code executes in foreground or suspended state but not in background state.

Comment: OK, when application is already in background code does not execute. But during switching it tries to redraw view and because  NSDocumentController.shared.currentDocument is already nil I got an error. My question is how to avoid it?